# How to run a (java) application at boot time on RaspberryrPi B+?

Tags: archlinux

How do I instruct rPi B+ to run java application at  boot time in ArchLinux, I mean, where do I add `java -jar octopus.jar` to execute at boot time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using [this tutorial](http://grammarofdev.blogspot.com/2013/11/autorun-startup-script-on-raspberry-pi.html).

To summarize it, here are the necessary steps:

1. Create the file for startup service: `vi /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service`
2. Fill the created file with the information needed to run **AND** install your service:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=myservice custom script
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
>
> [Service]
> Type=oneshot
> RemainAfterExit=yes
> ExecStart=/path_to_custom_scripts/myservice_startup_script.sh
> ```

3. Save the file
4. Edit and save the script file `/path_to_custom_scripts/myservice_startup_script.sh`
5. Install the service: `systemctl enable myservice.service`
6. Check state of the service: `systemctl is-enabled myservcice.service`

If the service is running, then the service script has been edited without errors and voila, that's it!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You can edit your own answer to include what you learned, how you used it and what seemed important to you. The answer will be improved and the people that downvoted might revoke that vote too.

Comment: First it is not my opinion, but rather a standard set for all of the stackexxchange sites. The rational behind it is to avoid link rot, and keep answers useful despite what may happen to the linked resource. Each down vote counts as -1 so if you see a big drop it is not one person's opinion, but rather the community. If you do as @Ghanima suggested and improve the answer I will remove my down vote - simply add a comment with an @ before my username and I will see it.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih On behalf of the community, thank you for sharing your experience :-) I'm sure that will help other people.

Answer (score 4):

Find a good overview as how to autostart scripts or services at the [Archlinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autostarting). A convenient way for simple testing is the use of cron. Edit crontab by `crontab -e` and use the alias `@reboot` to schedule a task to be started after reboot. Use full paths for you executables though.

Another typical way is to utilize the `systemd` default init framework that allows services to be enabled using the `systemctl` command.