# how to autorun a python program in raspberry pi when power supply is ON

Tags: python

how to autorun a python program in raspberry pi when power supply is ON.  we followed the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8iU9TnYFOV0 but it is not working

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange rpi. While we would love to help, there is really nothing to answer here. Please describe exactly what you want to achieve, exactly what you tried and exactly howw the actual outcomee differed from the expected one. We don't like to follow links - please include it all in text in your question.

Comment: Check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23451/rpi-b-java-application-at-boot-time/23452#23452 That should help. If something comes up, feel free to edit your question to ask that!

Comment: When Power is ON = when the system is booting (assuming anything won't fail before). There are tons of tutorials on the web about making linux run a **shell command** on startup. As you know, executing a python script is nothing else than firing a command. Just google `linux run script on startup` . For more detailed tutorial replace "Linux" with "Debian".

Answer (score 2):

You could use crontab for that

```
crontab -e
```

or

```
cron -e
```

depending of the OS you are using, and insert

```
@reboot python /path/to/file.py
```

that should do it, but remember to put the path to the full path to the file, this is essential.